# Override font size in different class td's

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
td {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;

}

td.botonver {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: #669900;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 12px;
}


    <?php>

    // code

    echo "<table>
                <tr><td>El nº total de registros es: ".$mi_agenda->numero_registros."</td>
                <td class=\"botonver\">".boton("Ver listado completo","index.php?operacion=listado")."</td></tr>
              </table>";
    ?>
```

Class "botonver" with that font size does not apply to cell td, it's 18px. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your HTML code as well.

Comment: The cell seems like it's inheriting the font size form elsewhere... If you're using a browser that supports it, right click in the cell and select "inspect element" and you'll be able to determine where the size is coming from.

Comment: The size is coming from td of 18px above, but I don't know why apply that and not class size. Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code in your question (http://jsfiddle.net/odqpzzp0/). Your implementation of the code must be the problem. That or the `boton` or `numero_registros` output is breaking the HTML. Can you provide a copy of the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but I believe this should work!

```
    td {
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 18px;

    }

    td.botonver {
        border: 1px solid white;
        background-color: #669900;
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 12px !important;
    }


echo '<table><tr><td>El nº total de registros es: '.$mi_agenda.'</td>
    <td class=botonver>'.boton("Ver listado completo","index.php?operacion=listado").'</td></tr>
              </table>';
```